# J2ME Image not Found

Tags: java-me, nokia

I am working on a menu with just simple image

```
Image x = Image.createImage("numbers.png");
listMenu.append(counter, x);
```

it's working well on the emulators with the Micro Edition SDK 3
but when I use the Nokia emulator S40 or deploy to my mobile S60
it's not working, it gave me "Cannot read numbers.png"

any ideas?

Comment: Alright smartass, Android won't know where to find your images either unless you give it the right path to where they are.

Comment: Do you see the numbers.png in the .jar file? If not how do you package your jar files? What is the tool?

Comment: I know that Android use J2ME, so I tagged it in the Question.

Comment: and I'm Just started on the field, I don't know how to put my images in the .jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you put your images in a `res` folder in your MIDlet's root directory.  Your `createImage()` call then becomes:

`Image x = Image.createImage("/res/numbers.png");`

Comment: thx alot, it's working well. put please, can you justify why :) !

Comment: Hi user628889!  You should upvote as well as saying "thx" in the comments.  It works because you're specifying an absolute path to the file, you're telling the handset exactly where to find it.

Comment: :) sorry but I am new here, my reputation is 1 :( it need 15 rep. to upvote